# Cultivation manga where the main character can drink beast blood to get stronger

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

He has a technique that allows him to drink beast blood without dying and get stronger from it. I think the technique was "sky devouring technique" or something like that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Please [edit] you question to add any additional details you can think of.

Comment: Are you the same fellow who spammed this comment all over Reddit?
"he recieved a cultivation technique from god that makes him stronger by drinking demon beast blood so he survived. I know that this is very general, but here are somethings that might make it different from other cultivation manhua of a similiar plot.-cultivators no longer use demon beast blood to get strong." All of them got deleted, but I want to know if there are two people looking for it.

Comment: If someone does post the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. If someone has an incorrect answer, but it makes you realize further details, please [edit] them into your question.

Comment: Is it me or there's a surge of 2-liners story-ID questions?

Comment: @Clockwork There's always been a lot of low quality id questions but there does seem to have been a bump recently for short manga ids I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

This might be *Matchless Emperor* as per [this list](https://demonweb4u.blogspot.com/2020/10/best-cultivation-mangasmanhua-you.html):

[image: Front cover of Matchless Emperor]

> A good for nothing poor boy whose always sleeps in class gets a cultivation book in which he believes nothing worth. He always gets bullied for not awakening his potential. When his only admirer betray him by his obtaining treasure and tries to kill him then he awakens his power by drinking beast blood. Then story begin....

Based on the translated pages I've found, his technique is named "Swallowing the Sky"

Found with a search for `manga "beast blood" cultivation`

Comment: Thank you this is the one I'm looking for

Comment: Don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.